# Can I use IIS Express to test a reverse proxy on my local machine>

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, iis-express

I want to implement a local reverse proxy website on my machine. I don't have admin rights to it. So I cannot use IIS manager. I have to use IIS express. I just want to know if I can use IIS express for proxies. I know how to do that in IIS (because it's all GUI), but can anyone direct me on how to do that in IIS express?

Contraints:
1. No admin rights on machine
2. Cannot install any program
3. ARR and url-rewrite not installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you not only need admin privileges, but YOU HAVE to install the application request routing (ARR).  Also you must have full version of IIS7.x

Comment: Actually I just found out that IIS Express cannot access websites on other servers. Though it has URL rewrite, it lacks ARR. So, the closest you can come to a reverse proxy on iis express is to produce clean urls (though strictly speaking, it's no proxy) using the url rewrite that is already there. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yes, to clarify I did not mean IIS Express , but the full version.